# Dedicated image style for media gallery teaser

Tags: 7, nodes, media

Is there any possiblity to define another dedicated image style for the teaser of a media gallery node only? I can change the default gallery thumbnail image style but this has also effect on the galleries overview page.

Because I like to create an image slider on the front page with the 5 newest galleries but need the image in another format then the default square thumbnail format.

Is there any possbility to do that so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve what I want. I used the [`Entity View Modes (evm)`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAAahUKEwjixrz1srvHAhXKVhoKHYylCzI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.drupal.org%2Fproject%2Fentity_view_mode&ei=db3XVaK4MsqtaYzLrpAD&usg=AFQjCNGG9es1Zz4HPC81m7Pybz6OXau1ZA&sig2=t05_HL28seHYHBke8lrJ4g) module. I created a custom view mode under **Configuration » Entity View Modes » File**.

This view mode is now available under **Structure » File types » Image » Manage file display**

Here I can select the checkbox **Image**. And then select my desired image style under the **Display settings** in tab **Image** select box **Image style**.

This new view mode is now usable in display suite. If you go to the content type **Gallery** and click on **Manage display** where display suite hooks in you can now choose the formatter **Rendered file** for the field **Gallery media**. In the formatter settings you'll find your new view mode. Select it and et voilà you get the image with your desired image style.

---

**DS solution**

I also found a solution with display suite itself. Without the needing for the additional Entity View Modes module.

Just create a new view mode for **File** using display suite. Then in the **Structure > File types** menu you can activate the view mode for **Images**. And choose your custom image style.

This view mode you can then select in the field template settings like in the description above.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own image style at [admin/config/media/image-styles](http://admin/config/media/image-styles) by click "[Add style](http://admin/config/media/image-styles/add)" link.

Use below code in your template file to fetch particular image style.

```
$my_style = image_style_url('your-img-style', 'image/uri');
<img src=' . $my_style . '/>
```

[More details about image style.](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/image_style_url/7)

Comment: Thx for your answer. How would I achieve using the new image style with display suite then?

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER, Don't know much about DS.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to do.

1. Create a new image style as @kalidasan mentioned in his answer.
2. Copy the template you are using from `Display Suite` `layout` directory and place it in your theme template directory.
3. Implement `hook_ds_pre_render_alter()` and from there apply the `image_style_url()` as mentioned by @kalidasan in his answer.

   `$vars['image_style'] = image_style_url('IMAGE_STYLE', 'IMAGE_URI');`
4. Modify the template you copied from `Display Suite` to render the `$image_style` you created from #3.

Comment: Thx for your answer. But when I use the DS  `ds-reset.tpl.php` layout. Where do I get the `IMAGE_URI` from?